# Docker Mysql+PHP [Port mismatch issue with terminal & PHP Application]

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have written a new docker-compose file for MySQL & PHP connection

From MySQL:

1. Port exposing `3315:3306`

From PHP:

1. To access a MySQL from PHP server, I have added line docker-compose.yml `links` as 'mysql' service name
2. Port exposing `30005:80`

My Folder structure & file [Image-1]

[image]

This is command, which I used to run the docker

`docker-composer --build up`

My running containers list  [Image-2]

[image]

This is how I'm accessing in terminal  [Image-3]

[image]

The Result of the PHP script is  [Image-4]

[image]

My problem to this configuration is, when you noticed the index.php file from the Image-1.

i have used port as 3306 to connect a mysql, but when you refer the Image-3. To connect a mysql in terminal, i have used port as 3315

Issue on this, Why i need to use 3306 as port in PHP application to MySQL server, instead of using mysql(In docker-compose.yml file) exposed port 3315.

In terminal, i can able to access correctly, but when we go for application i have this problem.

Someone can help me to understand the port mismatch in application & terminal for a MySQL connect.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

All your containers are in one isolated network. Mysql service has hostname - mysql and listens to port 3306.
The host machine listens to port 3315 and forwards packets into that network on port 3306.

Comment: didn't understand how I'm accessing the 3306 port instead of 3315.
In compose file clearly, I'm exposing port 3306 to 3315. Then I should always use 3315 right. But I'm not able to access that port via the application

Comment: As you can see in https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports the first port is exposed on the host and the last one - on the container